# PHP Loop, Add a comma after every loop except the last

Tags: php, html

I've got a query that loops through some product names and puts them down on the page.  As part of the loop, it adds a comma to the end, so it looks like this:

Products:  Shirts, Pants, Ties, Jackets,

Notice that I'm getting a comma after the last product.  Also, they are all links, so I can't use some strreplace fx or similar:

Here's my code:

```
<?php
 $product_query = mysql_query("select * from products_table);
 $row_product_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query);
 $totalRows_product_query = mysql_num_rows($product_query);
 ?>
 <strong>Products:  </strong>
 <?php if ($totalRows_product_query > 0) {  ?>
 <?php do { ?>
 <span><a href="link"><?php echo $row_product_query['products_name']; ?></a></span>
<strong>,&nbsp;</strong>
 <?php } while ($row_product_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query)); ?>
 <?php } ?><br />
```

What do I need to do to make that last comma not appear?

Thanks in advance as always.

Comment: Add it to a variable, and do [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the last comma.

Comment: Take a look at the php implode function:

Comment: Print the first link outside of the loop, then each additional link inside the loop with a comma proceeding it

Comment: @Tucker, perhaps post that as an answer since it is probably the "correct" solution

Comment: i think you only need check if is the last row , do not print comma , no need to change all your code , i write my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the php implode function

```
<?php
    $str = "";
    $product_query = mysql_query("select * from products_table");
    $row_product_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query);
    $totalRows_product_query = mysql_num_rows($product_query);
    $cnt = 0;
?>
<strong>Products:  </strong>
<?php if ($totalRows_product_query > 0) {  ?>
<?php do { 
    $arr[$cnt] = '<span><a href="link">'.$row_product_query['products_name'].'</a></span>';
    $cnt++;
<?php } while ($row_product_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($product_query)); ?>
<?php } 
    echo implode("<strong>,</strong>",$arr);
?><br />
```

Comment: Thanks Tucker (and everybody else)

Answer (score 0):

Fix how they are being stored/entered into the database?
otherwise, 
    `<?php echo str_replace(",", "", $row_product_query['products_name']); ?>` 
should work

Comment: Commas are added during the loop, they're not stored in DB `puts them down on the page. As part of the loop, it adds a comma to the end,`

Answer (score 0):

As @tucker said, you could use the implode function. [Implode Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). You would use it with an array like so

`$a_string = implode(",",$the_result_array);`

This would give you your desired results.